# Spring Memory Issue After Updating

Tags: spring, mongodb, memory, heap-memory, space

I was earlier using spring version 2.1.6-RELEASE with mongodb version 4.2 and now when i am updating spring version 2.4.10 which uses mongodb driver 4.1.2 and mongodb version 4.4 with gradle version 6.9.1. i am getting memory issues like heap space issues even though i have provided 8GB heap space still it is giving memory issues.
Can anyone help if it is version compatibility issue or any other with older version it was working fine and great but after updating giving memory issue. Help is appreciated. Thanks

i have tried increasing memory and profiling my code but still getting this. I am expecting that my code should work fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.